# Replace returns with spaces and commas with semicolons?

Tags: perl

I want to be able to be able to replace all of the line returns (\n's) in a single string (not an entire file, just one string in the program) with spaces and all commas in the same string with semicolons.

Here is my code:

```
    $str =~ s/"\n"/" "/g;
    $str =~ s/","/";"/g;
```

Comment: You may need to use the `s` modifier in order to be able to match newlines.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The `s` modifier only changes the meaning of `qr/./`.  An explicit `\n` works as expected without it on multiline input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to quote in your search and replace, only to represent a space in your first example (or you could just do `/ /` too).

```
$str =~ s/\n/" "/g;
$str =~ s/,/;/g;
```

Comment: actually, in perl the `/` is considered the quoting character (delimiter) here.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators had the details... the delimiter (which you choose, it doesn't have to be `/`) *quotes* the regexp.

Answer (score 10):

This will do it. You don't need to use quotations around them.

```
$str =~ s/\n/ /g;
$str =~ s/,/;/g;
```

Explanation of modifier options for the Substitution Operator (`s///`)

```
e       Forces Perl to evaluate the replacement pattern as an expression. 
g       Replaces all occurrences of the pattern in the string. 
i       Ignores the case of characters in the string. 
m       Treats the string as multiple lines. 
o       Compiles the pattern only once. 
s       Treats the string as a single line. 
x       Lets you use extended regular expressions.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [tr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html):

```
$str =~ tr/\n,/ ;/;
```